# Application accepts command line argument of the form : *argument but not of the form argument* or *argument*

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

For example if my program name is `test.c`

Then for the following run command the `argc = 2` instead of `4`.

`$test abc pqr* *xyz*`

Comment: you can try something like `$test "abc" "pqr*" "*xyz*"`

Comment: Depending on the number of files that start with `pqr`, you may input as many files. In that case, your argc will not be 2.

Comment: yes understood the reason for that. we can also use \* instead of *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because your shell / cmd.exe (no specifics are given!) use the `*` as file glob. If there are no files found that match the glob, the result will be empty.

Try calling you program like this:

```
test abc 'pqr*' 'xyz'
```

refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29 for details about globbing, and your shell's manual for details about escaping globs.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run:

```
$ echo abc pqr* *xyz*
```

and you will understand why you don't get the `argc` value you were expecting